# Map a forest or partition onto a segmentation image

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

Hi guys I'm doing this process:
MST-based Segmentation Algorithm

Algorithm MST
Input: A gray-scale image with P pixels and number R

Output: An image segmented into R regions

1. Map the image onto a primal weighted graph.
2. Find an MST of the graph.
3. Cut the MST at the R – 1 most costly edges.
4. Assign the average tree vertex weight to each vertex in each tree in the forest
5. Map the partition onto a segmentation image

For now, I've done all the steps , I took an colored image then I converted it to a grayscale, after that mapped the image onto a graph using jgraphT by assigning each vertex to the intensity of the pixel. Then, then I got the minimum spanning tree and cut it ,  finally I select the each tree in the forest and took avrge of the tree weight the assign it to each vertex .

Now for the last and the most important step
I ended with the vertices and the edge
how can I map this graph that I got onto the image and got the image segmentation ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Algorithm 1 of the paper "P. Felzenszwalb, D. Huttenlocher: Efficient Graph-Based Image Segmentation. IJCV 59(2) (September 2004)" might be what you are looking for. It can be found here:

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dph/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf

Input: A graph G=(V,E) with weighted egdes

Output: A segmentation of V into components

Sorting the weights with BucketSort and using the FastLookupSpecifics of JGraphD (=Default settings for a directed Graph) should give you an efficient implementation.